# abs function for float value in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I need to create a function abs for float with bitwise operators, this function return float value.

I can't use `<` or `>`.

I try this

```
(float)((int)f ^ ((int)f>>31)) - ((int)f>>31)
```

but for `-2.5` value I get `2.0`, it's not correct.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
float abs = Float.intBitsToFloat(Float.floatToIntBits(x) & 0x7FFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 2):

The most significant bit of a float is the sign bit.  So... you should be able to use the bitwise & operator to clear that bit to get the absolute value.

Use this as your mask to bitwise and with your value:

```
0x7fffffff
```

Comment: Yes, but how? You can't get to the bit representation in Java.

Comment: @chiastic-security:  Oh, but you *can*.   You have to keep it in your head, but every numeral value has a bitwise representation.

Comment: @chiastic-security: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits-float- and of course http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat-int-

Comment: @chiastic-security: Peter's answer took mine one step further and provided the code to convert the float to int bits that you can then & with the mask, after which he converts the int bits back to a float.

Comment: @MichaelKrause yes, didn't know about those methods. Nice. And I see they're `native`, which suggests you wouldn't otherwise be able to do it.